# get comments on a post from database using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to fetch all the `comments` on each post from database using ajax, but I'm having some problem.

Here is the **problem**.

I've `home` route where I've fetched all the `posts` from database and I didn't fetched `comments` on those posts.

Now I want to fetch `comments` for each post using Ajax, such like when someone leave a comment on a post it should be added to the database and then fetch from database on the fly.

The comment is added via **Ajax** successfully , but I'm not able to fetch them from database using Ajax.

Here is my **Code**:

**Controller**

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

**index** method inside `HomeController`

```
   public function index()
{

    $post  = Post::all();

    // I've used this approach to get comments
    //$posts = Post::with('comments')->get();


    return view('home')->with( array('posts'=>$posts ) );
}
```

I've loop through all the posts from the database , and so I've also a **form** there inside that loop to leave comment for that post.

** `Form` For leaving a Comment**

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
   <p>$post->description</p>

   <div class="show_comments_{{ $post->id }}"></div> 



  <form action="{{ url('comment',$post->p_id)  }}" method="POST"  > 
   @csrf
<textarea 
   name="body"
   placeholder="Write A Suggestion" 
   data-autosize-input='{ "space": 100 }' 
   rows="50" cols="100"
   name="comment"  
   class="form-control comment body">

 </textarea> 
 <input type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}">


    <!-- user Id of the logged In one -->

  <input type="text" class="user_id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}" name="user_id">

        <!-- post id  -->

  <input type="text" class="post_id" name="post_id" value="{{$post->p_id}}">



   <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger formcomment" value = 'Comment' style="margin:10px;">Comment</button> 
</form>


@endforeach
```

When I click on **Comment** button the following code runs to insert the comment into the `comments` [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuprO.png).

**Ajax Request**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('.formcomment').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    // these are id's

    var body = form.find('.body').val();
    var post_id = parseInt(form.find('.post_id').val());
    var user_id = parseInt(form.find('.user_id').val());

    // alert(body);
    // alert('this is post'+post_id);
    // alert('This is user id'+user_id);


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/comment/'+post_id,
        data: {body:body, post_id:post_id, user_id:user_id,  _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'},
        success: function(data) {


            $(".show_comments_"+post_id).append("<div style = 'color:red;'>"+data.msg+"</div>");
          $(".name_"+user_id).append("<div>"+data.user_id+"</div>")

        }
    });
});


});
```

The comments are added successfully to the table mentioned in the image, and I've fetched them back in the form mentioned above, but that is fetched when I refresh the page, I want to fetch them when someone leave comment on the fly, since it is inserting through ajax, but fetching after refreshing the page.

**Updated**

`/comment` code is here

```
public function storeComments(Request $request,Comment $body,$post_id){


 if($request->ajax()){
    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->user_id =  Auth::user()->id;
    $comment->post_id = $post_id;
    $comment->body = Input::get('body');

    $comment->save();
    $response = array(
                'status' => 'success',
                'msg' => 'Setting created successfully',
            );
            return Response::json($response);
            return 'yes';
        }else{
            return 'no';
        }
```

}

comments table with 'dummy' data [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcp2p.png)
I'm trying to solve this problem from last 2 days, please help.
Thanks

A link which I studied for this is [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/get-all-posts-with-all-comments)

Comment: Do you use php? Is there return in it ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I'm using Laravel @bakero98

Comment: are you getting the comments in response? can please add the '/comment' code where you are sending the ajax request.

Comment: I've updated the post, please check it out @ShivendraSingh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form code update.

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
   <p>$post->description</p>

    <div class="show_comments_{{ $post->p_id}}"></div>

  // I found this code on laracast, at end there is link.
   @if (count($post->comments))
       @foreach($post->commnents as $comment)
         <small>$comment->body</small>
       @endforeach
    @else 
        No comments Found
  @endif
```

store the data in json response.

```
if($request->ajax()){
    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->user_id =  Auth::user()->id;
    $comment->post_id = $post_id;
    $comment->body = Input::get('body');

    $comment->save();
   //add the comment in response 
    return response()->json(['msg'=>$comment->body]);
}
```

in ajax need to display the message that we have successfully added the data

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/comment/'+post_id,
        data: {body:body, post_id:post_id, user_id:user_id,  _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'},
        success: function(data) {
            //get the msg from success response. 
               $(".show_comments_"+post_id).append("<div style = 'color:red;'>"+data.msg+"</div>");

        }
    });
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194974/discussion-on-answer-by-shivendra-singh-get-comments-on-a-post-from-database-usi).