# get the name and image of the user who is leaving comment

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I've opened this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56599519/get-comments-on-a-post-from-database-using-ajax) . I have the same code that is there, please have a look at that.

I'm getting the `comment` body on the fly, perfectly fine, **But** Now I want to fetch the user `name` and `image` when the user leaves a comment and show it on the screen below the post description.

**Problem**

Right now I can get only the `user_id`, how can I get the `user_name` and the image?

My comments table where I'm inserting the comments looks like:[image: this].

So how can I get the `user_name` of the user who is leaving a comment, right now I can only get the `user_id`

For better understanding, I want to get the `user_name` below this line in **Ajax Request Code**

```
$(".show_comments_"+post_id).append("<div style = 'color:red;'>"+data.msg+"</div>")
```

You can see I've tried for the name, but I'm unable to get the `user_name` and `image` who is leaving a comment.

**Note**:

I've `models` that have the perfectly fine relations from `posts` to `users`
and vice versa.

I'm new to laravel.

Updated :

In Ajax handling `Controller` I have code something like this :

```
 public function storeComments(Request $request,Comment $body,$post_id){
   if($request->ajax()){
    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->user_id =  Auth::user()->id;
    $comment->post_id = $post_id;
    $comment->body = Input::get('body');

    $comment->save();
   return response()->json( ['msg'=>$comment->body,'user_id' =>$comment->user_id] );       

    }


}
```

I'm trying to load image but I got the following

[this is what I got instead of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSNR6.png)

Thanks In advance.

Comment: In your AJAX handling Controller code, you will have to fetch the users details from 'user_id'. Save those details in a variable or array and then send it back to the AJAX request.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the post with `controller` you are talking about, what should I add there to get the `name` and the `image` of the user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..
When you do `Auth::user` it retrieves the current user model which will allow you to access user data

```
   public function storeComments(Request $request,Comment $body,$post_id){
    if($request->ajax()){
    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->user_id =  Auth::user()->id;
    $comment->post_id = $post_id;
    $comment->body = Input::get('body');


    $comment->save();
   return response()->json( ['msg'=>$comment->body,'user_id' =>$comment->user_id, 'user_name' => Auth::user()->name, 'user_img' => Auth::user()->image] );       

    }
}
```

Comment: that's cool, working ! but how could I append image.I've all images in folder `uploads/avatars`.
what should I write in `src` exp:
like how can I append it like `data.user_image` to `img` element
$(".image_"+post_id).append("<img src = 'asset(uploads/avatars/...)'>")

Comment: I've write something like this :
`$(".image_"+post_id).append("<img src = 'asset(uploads/avatars/'+data.user_image) />")`
but this loads just an icon type not the real image

Comment: it depends where you have stored the images.. Image can be stored in public folder i.e. in root/public, or in storage/app/public.

Comment: I've stored them in `uploads/avatars` but I got only an icon type , not real image of the user after writing above code, is that correct way ?

Comment: care to provide a screenshot?

Comment: check out the post, I've updated it with screenshot for you! @MekjkrhG

Comment: i found some useful link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480550/how-to-load-all-the-images-from-one-of-my-folder-into-my-web-page-using-jquery

Comment: can you help me a little more, when the comment is done, I want to make the textarea empty, how can i do that , because right now comment is done successful but there is text in the textarea , I want to vanish that text when comment is done, any idea ? please share

Comment: glad you solved the image issue @contributor. as for the other question you better make a new post for that as its is going off topic now.