# Add new Comment from new line not adjacent to the previous one

Tags: html, css

I've a `div` with `.nameImage` class.

```
  <div class="nameImage" style="border:1px solid black;">
         <div class="image_{{$post->p_id}}"></div>
         <div class="name_{{$post->p_id}}"></div>
         <div class="show_comments_{{ $post->p_id }}"></div>
  </div>
```

These three things `image`, `name` and s`comment-body` come from `response()->json([,,])` and I've appended them like :

```
   $(".image_"+post_id).append( "<img style = 'width:30px;height:30px;border-radius:50%;' src='"+ folder + data.user_image +"'>" )
   $(".name_"+post_id).append(data.name)
   $(".show_comments_"+post_id).append(data.msg)
```

In that `div` I have appended `image`, `name` and `comment-body` of the user when someone leaves a comment all these three things comes into the above div
.

The first comment looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMvGo.png)
But When I add new Comment, that comment's info like 'image' is being attached to the **first** comment's `image` and the `name` is attached with first comment's `name` and so as the `comment body`.

When I add new comment in the presence of first comment, it becomes something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhhhc.png)

You can see that the `image` for the second `comment` is being attached adjacent to the first comment's image.

I want to add new comment from new line or you can say new div.

I've used CSS something like this:

```
.nameImage{

  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row

 }
```

But that is not solving the problem.

How can I get the second comment separate from the first comment in **new** line with `image`, `name` and `comment-body`.

After some suggestions, Now I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IETHT.png)

Comment: It depends a lot on how you are adding the new comment - it looks like that is causing the issue. Can you post that code? And the HTML for situation with the second comment would be helpful

Comment: When a comment is posted, it looks like a comment consists of an image, a name, and the comment. So when a new comment is posted, you should be adding a whole element consisting of those 3 things, which means a new `nameImage` `div` I would think.

Comment: I'm getting all these three things from `response()->json()`, and I'm just appending them into the `divs` that are inside the .nameImage `div`.

so the first comment is okay, and I want to add the second comment just below the first one with all these three things .

Comment: you should use display: block instead of display: flex

Comment: that is not working dear @ShovonDas

Comment: I've updated ,please have a look @OliverTrampleasure

Comment: please check the updated post @lurker

Comment: The results you are getting (that you don't want) are exactly what your code is telling it to do. You are individually appending an image to the prior image, a name to the prior name, and a comment to the prior comment. See my first comment about needing to treat the entire comment as a single entity.

Comment: Yes, you've marked the correct thing, and I understand that the problem is there, but I don't know how to solve it ? @lurker 
how can I add a whole element consisting of these three things ?

Comment: Your whole collection of comments need to be inside a `div` that holds them. Then each comment would be a `div` like your `nameImage` `div`. When you add a comment, you would append to the comment collection `div` the `nameImage` `div`. You can append all the details of that `div` (including the sub-`div` elements).

Comment: okay I add this :
<div class = 'nameImage_'{{$post->id}}>// here these three things will come</div>

But Now I got two comments side by side,now the only issue is to make the second comment from next line

Comment: I've added the new result via screenshot, please have a look at that, now the only issue is the new comment should be from the next line, not side by side with the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your overall scheme is for showing comments, but here's an approach that would do what I think you want.

First, you need a `div` that holds the collection of comments. That `div` would contain comments which each would be a `div` holding all of the elements needed for a single comment:

```
<div id='commentCollection'>
  <!-- first comment -->
  <div class="nameImage" id="comment_#" style="border:1px solid black;">
    <div class="comment_image"></div>
    <div class="comment_name"></div>
    <div class="comment_text"></div>
  </div>
  ... <!-- more comments -->
</div>
```

Note that I included a  unique `id` for each comment, and that `id` is "comment_#". You can use the `post_id` for #. *It's important to keep all id's on a page unique.* That's the point of an `id`. *And classes should be general and typically not unique*. Those are used for controlling the CSS attributes of whole groups/collections of elements of a given class. For this purpose, I created classes `comment_image`, `comment_name` and `comment_text` so you can control how these look in CSS. They're uniqueness per comment is established by their parent `div` that has a unique `id`. If you find you need to locate each individual comment text, image, or name uniquely, you can give them each a unique `id` as well using the `post_id` if you wish.

Now when you add a comment, in your jQuery you need to:

(1) Append a new empty `.nameImage` `div` (a new comment) to the `#commentCollection` `div`. Give it the id `comment_${post_id}`.

(2) Append your image, name, and comment text to that new comment `div`:

```
$(`#comment_${post_id} > div.comment_image`).append( "<img style = 'width:30px;height:30px;border-radius:50%;' src='"+ folder + data.user_image +"'>" )
$(`#comment_${post_id} > div.comment_name`).append(data.name)
$(`#comment_${post_id} > div.comment_text`).append(data.msg)
```

Anyway, something like that. I wrote the above somewhat quickly and did not test it. I expect that you should be able to get the idea and run with it. Don't just copy this code, try it, and come back and say "it doesn't work" without understanding it and adjusting it as you need first.

Comment: For better understanding this , I've opened a question earlier , I've the same code that is there, in addition to the accepted answer code there.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56599519/get-comments-on-a-post-from-database-using-ajax

Please have a look

Comment: I've tried this , but that is not working, it is giving me comments side by side, I want a new comment from new line to be shown there not to .
be adjacent to the prior one. @lurker

Comment: @contributor At this point, you need to work on your CSS for your comment `div`s now to get the comments not to be side-by-side but to be vertical. I did not address that part. My answer helped you untangle your authors, images, and comment text so that they were separate. I don't know what else you have around this information on the same page, so it's hard to for me to recommend something definitive without context. You could try using this CSS item for your class `imageName`: `float: left; clear: right;`