# get all posts with their comments from database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've got a system in which there are `users` who create posts and they can comment on `posts` as well.

Here are migrations:

`users` table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('gender')->default('Male');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('city')->default('Peshawar');
    $table->string('avatar')->default('user.png');
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
}
```

`posts` table

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {


        $table->bigIncrements('p_id');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->integer('user_id');   // this should be user id nothing else
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

`comments` table

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('user_id'); // who has done comment
        $table->integer('post_id');  // on which post comment has been done
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Models**

`User` Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable{
use Notifiable;

// custom function used for relationshisp
// user can have many posts

public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}

// user can have many comments as well

public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

}

`Post` Model

```
class Post extends Model{
   // posts belongs to one user
   public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
  }


   public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
   } 

 }
```

`Comment` Model

```
class Comment extends Model
```

{

```
// doing this we could insert data into comment table
protected $fillable =['user_id','post_id','body'];
// we need two(2) relations here
// relation of comment with post

// relation of comment with user
```

// 1. comment belongs to one post

```
public function post(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

// 2. comment belongs to a user as well

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

}

`route`

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Here is the `index` method in `HomeController`

```
public function index(){
    $posts = Post::with('comments')->get();
    // $comments = Comment::all();

    return view('home')->with( array('posts'=>$posts ) );
}
```

**Problem**

So when I visit `/home` I want to get all posts with their **comments**.

As you can see I've retrieved `posts` with their `comment` like this:

```
$posts = Post::with('comments')->get();
```

And then I'm passing it to `home.blade.php`.
Here is what I'm doing at `home.blade.php` to achieve this task.

**View** `/home.blade.php`

```
@foreach($posts as $post)

     <h4 class="media-heading">{{$post->user->name}}</h4>
     <small>{{$post->created_at}}</small>

     <p>{{$post->description}}</p>

     <!-- trying to retrieve comments with each post -->

             @if (count($post->comments))
                  @foreach($post->commnents as $comment)
                      <small>$comment->body</small>
                   @endforeach
             @else 
                  No comments Found
             @endif 




 @endforeach
```

It gives me this error

> Undefined variable: post (View: F:\application\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Keeping in mind those `models` and their `relationships` with each other, am I doing it in the wrong way to retrieve comments for each post? If so, how can I get all the `posts` with their `comments` and when there are no `comments` it should say `no comments found`.

Here is what the result return by `dd($posts)`
[dd($posts) returning this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJYld.png), have a look at the comments field, that is empty.

The `network` tab is showing the following [image: this]
Please help, Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Look into the trace of the error in which line is the exception.

Comment: Also, you have a typo here: `@foreach($post->commnents`

Comment: it highlights the problem in `if(count($post->comments))`

Comment: try to `@php dd($posts); @endphp` at the top of home.blade.php, then you can see what is inside the posts.

Comment: try to fix the typo as porloscerros said.

Comment: where is the typo ? @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: in the foreach `$post->commnents` must be `$post->comments`

Comment: I fixed that,that error is solved , but now  I can't get comments , it says `no comments found` meaning that `if` block fails, although I have comments in comments table @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: `dd($posts)` shows a collection of `posts` with some internal arrays @Muhammad

Comment: but is there a comments field?

Comment: another thing, in the query you are not bringing the related user, it is strange that you do not get an error when you want to show it in the view `{{$post->user->name}}`. Add 'user' inside the with: `$posts = Post::with(['user', 'comments'])->get();`

Comment: no, please have a look at the migrations @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: ok, but the related comments will be inside a comments field of the Post Object

Comment: I've added screenshot of what the `dd($posts)` is returning, please have a look at the post, you can see the `comment` field, that is empty, are you talking about that ? @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: how would you try to get all the comments with each posts and then show it in the view ? please share that so that I'll get an idea, am I doing it correctly ? @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Well, clearly the comments relation is empty. Is it the same for all Posts? I'm seeing that in the migrations you did not add the foreign keys.

Comment: Yes , I didn't add any kind of foreign keys , because somewhere I read that I don't need that.

Plus I'm just a beginner in laravel, 
_Well, clearly the comments relation is empty. Is it the same for all Posts_? 
A comments table is kind of pivot table with `user_id` and `post_id` as foreign keys but I didn't added them as `foreign keys` is that a problem ?

Comment: Creating the foreign key constraints, will force referential integrity at the database level. So, for example, if you try to add a comment with the wrong post_id, will throw you an exception. The answer posted by MekjkrhG makes sense, take a look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its probably because of this..

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {


        $table->bigIncrements('p_id'); <---
        $table->text('description');
        $table->integer('user_id');   // this should be user id nothing else
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

any reason why you are using p_id instead of id? relations work so that id of post is matched to the post_id in the comments table.. if you using this u have to specify this custom key when you are creating the relationship..

check out https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

Comment: But that leads to an another problem , now ajax commenting is not working ! @MekjkrhG

Comment: Here is the code link,

I've the same code till now , but commenting on the fly is not working, before the fix you suggested it was working fine;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56599519/get-comments-on-a-post-from-database-using-ajax?noredirect=1#comment99778179_56599519

Comment: ah reminder.. if you changed the migration from p_id to id.. you have to update the codes which were using p_id to id.. else it wont work. do u get any errors?

Comment: even the comment is not storing into into the DB, after this change, the code is there that I've provided the link @MekjkrhG

Comment: did u rollback the migration and change the p_id to id? and after that migrate again?

Comment: Yes but I manually change `p_id` to `id` from `phpmyadmin`.

I got this in console  : `500 Internal Server Error 214ms`, in firefox  `XHR` tab

Comment: ah thats not the right way to do it.. you can either rollback the migration and re-migrate after changing the value.. or rename the column from p_id to id.. 

check rename column here.. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#column-modifiers

but since u have already done update the post table migration file from p_id to id. 

change all the $post->p_id to $post->id like in your form post

`<form action="{{ url('comment',$post->p_id)  }}" method="POST"  > `
to
`<form action="{{ url('comment',$post->id)  }}" method="POST"  > `

and any other place where you have used p_id to id.

Comment: Yesh I've already changed the `p_id` to `id` then I changed that in `phpmyadmin` manually.
And also changed other places from `p_id` to `id`, still same problem

Comment: can u further explore the console error `500 Internal Server Error 214ms` from network tab. it will show the exact error

Answer (score 1):

Try passing your post custom key as third argument to the relation:

**Comment** Model

```
public function post(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'post_id', 'p_id');
}
```

---

Maybe a better option will be, change the key of the table posts to 'id' to agree with the conventions of Laravel. Create a new migration and run it.

```
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->renameColumn('p_id', 'id');
});
```

---

Another option would be, creating the foreign key constraints, to force referential integrity at the database level:

**posts** table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('p_id');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

**comments** table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned(); 
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();  
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('p_id')->on('posts');
    });
}
```

You will have to rollback and re-run the migrations (you will lose the data saved in DB).

Comment: Note the two firsts options are the suggested by MekjkrhG's answer. Feel free to [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answers if them helped to solve your problem ;)